# SQL command timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ssis

In my asp.net, I creaate a `SqlConnection` and a `SqlCommand` bound to this `SqlConnection`. Then I set the `CommandTimeout` property of the `SqlCommand` to 1 hour.
This `SqlCommand` will call a stored procedure in the database. Inside the stored procedure, I will run a SSIS using the following command.

```
master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /ISSERVER "' + @PackageName + '" /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True'
```

This SSIS can take quite a long time. If the SSIs takes more than 1 hour, then the `SqlCommand` will timeout. But then what happens to the SSIS? Will the package still run until finish or will it be stopped when it is timeout? And how about the result? Will it be rolled back like a transaction or how do I check the data integrity?

Comment: Have you tried setting a shorter timeout to see what happens?  Would it be possible (assuming the SSIS package continues to run if the connection times out) to simply use the connection to start the package, and then check periodically to see if the package finished (maybe have the package write to a table the results of its run)?  Just spitballing here as I haven't worked with SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've tried and it seems that the SSIS will continue, despite the web page saying it is timeout.
Checking on the Integration Services Catalogs > "Package" > Reports > All Executions show its status as 'Running'. And I also see more data inserted to my database.
Then after waiting for some time, the status becomes 'Succeeded'.